# virtualbox hard disk not refreshing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, virtualbox

I've resized my HDD on VirtualBox to 40GB, although it is showing that in disk management the actual size is still 20GB.

[Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E90Yy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be similar to this issue? https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9103

Maybe that's because you have snapshots of this VM. Do you have any?